# Error reading file in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I followed all the instructions in [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com):

```
gem install jekyll bundler
jekyll new my-awesome-site
cd my-awesome-site
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Then, when I browse to http://localhost:4000 there is a blank page and the following errors in the Command Prompt:

```
Error reading file C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/default.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/page.html
Error reading file C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.2.0/_layouts/post.html
```

This is happening because I'm using Jekyll in partition `D:` while Ruby is installed in partition `C:`. As a matter of fact if I install all in one partition there are no errors but I prefer to keep all the projects in partition `D:`. I believe the problem is in `rb_sysopen`.

Any solutions? Thanks.

This is part of my `Gemfile.lock`:

```
PLATFORMS

- x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES

- jekyll (= 3.2.1)
- minima

RUBY VERSION

- ruby 2.3.1p112

BUNDLED WITH

- 1.13.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to generate the website without encountering errors: Just copy `_includes`, `_layouts`, `_sass` from the installation directory of the theme `C:\Ruby23\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\minima-1.2.0` to the project directory, i.e. `D:\www\my-awesome-site`.

Jekyll will first check the files of the theme in the project directory.

Of course this is just a workaround.